# Django ORM query for filtering product price between two number is not working properly

Tags: django, orm

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    product_image_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/product',blank = False)
    product_image_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/product', blank = False)
    product_image_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/product', blank = False)
    product_image_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'photos/product',blank = False)
    product_description = models.TextField()
    category_id = models.ForeignKey(Categories,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subcategory_id = models.ForeignKey(SubCategories, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('product_detail',args = [self.category_id.slug , self.subcategory_id.slug, 
        self.slug ])
```

'''view'''

```
val=request.POST.get('value')
                val = re.findall("\d+", val) # code to get all inigers from string
                min_price = int(val[0])
                max_price = int(val[1]) 
                print(min_price)
                print(max_price)
                ***product = Product.objects.filter(category_id = categories,is_active = 
                      True,price__gte = min_price, price__lte = max_price)***
```

## when i give value greater than max_value  product object returns null object

## I want all objects between the two min_value and max_value

Comment: Try changing the field type of price to Integer.
        price = models.IntegerField()

Comment: you're using price as character field so you cant filter it in range. You need int or decimal